# How to extract objects in Jmeter using JSONPath extractor

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jsonpath, json-path-expression

Hello i am using Jmeters JSONPath extractor, and the i am trying to extract certain fields from a response which is structured like the JSON below.  I am trying to only extract the names of the child objects and not the details inside them, so something like:

```
Result[0]= key1
Result[1]= key2
Result[3]= key3
```

Would I be able to do this using JSONPath extractor

```
{
   "output":{
      "key1":{
         "field1": "value1",
         "field2": "value2"
      },
      "key2":{
         "field1": "value1",
         "field2": "value2"
      },
      "key3":{
         "field1": "value1",
         "field2": "value2"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's even possible with JSON Path Extractor, however it's very easy achievable with [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) which provides [`keys` function](https://jmespath.org/proposals/functions.html#keys) fully covering your use case, the relevant query is as simple as:

```
keys(output)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)